# An excercise about (transfinite) sequences of cardinals.

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

The excercise is as follows

> Let us say that $D\subset\kappa^{<\kappa}$ is **dense** if for any $s\in\kappa^{<\kappa}\exists t\in D$ such that $s\subset t$.
>   Prove that if $\kappa$ is regular, for every family of dense subsets $\{D_\alpha|\alpha<\kappa\}$ there is $x\in\kappa^\kappa$ so that $\forall\alpha<\kappa\exists s\in D_\alpha$ such that $s\subset x$.

I am having trouble visualizing the situation: intuitively I would build $x$ inductively, exploiting the fact that each $D_\alpha$ is dense. Anyhow I can't write a proper definition nor I see where $\kappa$ regular comes into play.

Comment: So, **dense** actualy means cofinal. $\kappa$ regular says that its cofinality is $\kappa$...

Comment: @OlivierRoche "dense actually means cofinal". What do you mean? "dense" as defined here is a property of subsets of $\kappa^{<\kappa}$, while "cofinal" is a property of subsets of $\kappa$...

Comment: @OlivierRoche You could interpret "dense" as "cofinal in the poset $\kappa^{<\kappa}$", but then there's something to prove to show that if $\kappa$ has cofinality $\kappa$, $\kappa^{<\kappa}$ has cofinality $\kappa$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can construct an increasing sequence $\langle s_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ over $\kappa^{<\kappa}$ such that $s_\alpha\in D_\alpha$ as follows: for $\alpha=0$, take any $s_0\in D_0$. If $\alpha=\beta+1$, take any $s_{\beta+1}\supseteq s_\beta$ such that $s_{\beta+1}\in D_{\beta+1}$. 
If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, choose $s_\alpha\supseteq \bigcup_{\xi<\alpha} s_\xi$ satisfying $s_\alpha\in D_\alpha$. (The assumption $\kappa$ is regular is necessary to ensure $\bigcup_{\xi<\alpha}s_\xi$ has length $<\kappa$.)

Then take $x=\bigcup_\alpha s_\alpha$: if $x$ is not a $\kappa$-sequence, make $x$ longer by putting any elements after $x$ so that $x\in \kappa^\kappa$. We can see that some initial segment of $x$ is a member of $D_\alpha$ by the construction.

Comment: And regularity is used precisely at the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oops, I did not notice it. Thanks for mentioning it.